# How to retrieve data from an added-to-homescreen web page

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, shortcut

Not sure which stack to ask this on...

I would like to retrieve data from one of those added to homescreen web page shortcuts so that I can try and apply it to that same website either in Safari or in another shortcut.

Specifically, I'm talking about Wordle. The shortcut I'd created for the Wordle game when it was on powerlanguage.co.uk gets forwarded every time to the nytimes URL and it has all my game stats, but the game is squeezed because there's an added nytimes location header at the top and a tool bar at the bottom which shrinks the game interface.

If I go to the nytimes URL in Safari, the interface is good, but my stats are gone. Very annoying.

I spoke with someone at nytimes and they say there's no way to transfer the game stats from the homescreen shortcut to the Safari browser. I'm hoping someone here knows how to prove them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got half way there! I was able to export my stats from the old homescreen shortcut using a Siri Shortcut someone shared on reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/s8vbrz/wordle_importexport/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

That shortcut runs some JavaScript to export the stats which are in JavaScript localStorage and then I can import them into the nytimes site in Safari, but the next problem is:

1. I cannot create a new homescreen shortcut that keeps/transfers the stats
2. There's no way to access the share menu in the homescreen shortcut to try to import them there either

Still hoping someone has a clever way to accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for transferring Wordle data using this tool: https://sethmlarson.dev/blog/wordle-stats

This works great in any browser, but I found it a little tricky when dealing with a web page saved to the Home Screen, since the "Add to Home Screen" command does not copy over any storage data.

I was in a similar situation, trying to transfer my old `https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/` link (saved to the Home Screen) to `https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html`.

Since the saved Home Screen web page doesn't provide you with an address bar to navigate to the tool mentioned above, you could tap the Settings (gear) icon in the top right corner of the newly added NYTimes Worlde saved web page, and follow the Twitter link, taking you to the @NYTGames account. From there, you can scroll down or search for this tweet:
https://mobile.twitter.com/NYTGames/status/1532414444575375361

Alternatively, enter the URL for the Wordle stats tool in the "Search Twitter" input field, which should help you reach the page. The idea is basically to get to a tool such as the one mentioned within the newly added Home Screen site.

From there, follow the instructions on the site to reset your statistics. Note the one caveat that this tool currently is not able to reset your current streak.

**EDIT**: I found another similar solution, using the same concept of finding a way to navigate outside the saved New York Times site, but doing so by getting to Google and using different tool to fix, which purportedly allows you to set the current streak: https://www.reddit.com/r/wordle/comments/v15u3i/fixing_wordle_stats_for_those_who_have_ios/